# How to start a process from an IIS hosted WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, hosting

I would like to run a process from an intranet client on the WCF service side. In my case a client asks a server to create a new process on the server's machine under the provided credentials. WCF service is hosted on IIS 7.5 and I start a process using this code

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe")
{
    UserName = "some user",
    Password = MakeSecureString("some password"),
    UseShellExecute = false,
    LoadUserProfile = true
};

Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
```

This code works if I host WCF service as a self-hosted console application running under admin user and I see the notepad started under another user. It fails on IIS with no exception, but process is immediately terminated

```
process.HasExited = true;
process.ExitCode = -1073741502;
```

On IIS WCF application is running under the user with admin rights and has got full trust defined in web.config. I cannot use self  hosted application as it doesn't support easy continuous delivery (like WebDeploy with IIS web farms).

**Q:** How can I start a process on a server side from WCF service hosted on IIS?

EDIT:
I stumbled upon this [post](http://www.astahost.com/info.php/creating-process-alternate-credentials-createprocessasuser_t12663.html), with similar issues and I tried all the methods there, including all possible variations for Process.Start and P/Invoke with CreateProcessWithLogonW and CreateProcessAsUser I also tried granting additional permissions to users. Non of this would work with the error messages identical to the ones the guy had posted.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample?

Comment: It's not possible without dirty hacks. I didn't do it.

Comment: I didn't make it clear. You cannot do this. Event when trying to authenticated with `CreateProcessWithLogonW` or `CreateProcessAsUser`. This is not supported by OS and is considered a security flaw so you cannot legitimately make this work. Malware do this, but I am no specialist in that area and the security holes usually get patched pretty quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oleksii, the point is that if you host the WCF service in a console application, there is a windows session (a user logged in and Windows Explorer loaded) for that user and the notepad is opened and shown for that user, so you see it in the UI.

when you host your WCF service in IIS, being a server, IIS requires and allows no user interaction and works also if no user is logged in; in that context there is no UI to host your notepad or other UI enabled applications, you could execute a process for elaboration or other batch jobs but not render a windows UI application, because Windows Explorer is not loaded for you and there is no place to render your process's UI.

Comment: I want WCF Service  hosted in IIS (with user A in AppPool), and impersonate with another user B when I call to my command EXE (commandline, not UI) using Process.Start. Any suggestions? Maybe not possible.

Answer (score 1):

here is what I use to call GnuPGP to do encryption. How does your setup compare?

```
private int ExecuteCommand(string arguments, string passPhrase, int timeout)
        {
            Process processObject;
            ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(_executablePath, arguments);


            pInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            pInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            pInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            pInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processObject = Process.Start(pInfo);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(passPhrase))
            {
                processObject.StandardInput.WriteLine(passPhrase);
                processObject.StandardInput.Flush();
            }

            string result = processObject.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string error = processObject.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            if (!processObject.WaitForExit(timeout))
            {
                throw new TimeoutException("GnuPG operation timeout. Waited " + timeout + " milliseconds ");
            }

            int exitcode = processObject.ExitCode;

            Error = error;
            Output = result;

            return exitcode;

        }
```

Comment: No that wouldn't help after this line `processObject = Process.Start(pInfo);` it has HasExited set to true.

Comment: actually I am, it is a test harness that tests capabilities of other software to detect a process start.

Comment: Then test it with a simpler program - one without a UI.

Comment: @DustinDavis, do you call ExecuteCommand within WCF Service hosted in IIS ?

Answer (score 1):

There's an apppool setting to make sure it loads the user profile.

```
loadUserProfile Optional Boolean attribute.

Specifies whether IIS loads the user profile for the application pool identity. Setting    
this value to false causes IIS to revert to IIS 6.0 behavior. IIS 6.0 does not load the 
user profile for an application pool identity.

The default value is false.
```

That along with being a domain user as the identity with enough permissions might work??  I know that at a minimum the user will need a user profile.

That said, it's a little bit of an odd architecture.  It seems like a better arch would be to have a persistent process like a windows service that the site communicates with but I'm not sure what your constraints are.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This make sense. With IIS it would be easier to deliver the product via WebDeploy as I can create a web farm. That said, I tried Win Service and had the same issues there. I am reversing to Command line hosting and script deployment as it is painful to configure this on IIS.